# Restangular: why does post not update the collection?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Let's say I have the following...

```
myService = Restangular.all('things');
myService.getList().then(
  // success
  function(things) {
      $scope.things = things;
  },
  // failure
  function(things) {
    // do whatever, stuff failed
  }
)
```

Now I have `$scope.things` which is a collection of `things` from the api, all  well and good.

I want to post a new `thing`, and return the promise so I can deal with the pass/fail elsewhere

```
return $scope.things.post(newThing) // A promise...
```

However, doing things this way DOESN'T automatically add my new `thing` to the `$scope.things` collection. Why not? I've seen questions that link to the [enhanced promises](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#enhanced-promises) section of restangular docs and mention the "push" method, but that doesn't help me because `$scope.things` has no "push" method.

What's going on here? Where am I getting confused.

Comment: There is an alternate solution without refreshing the whole list using push() method. I have answered this in a similar question. Please check below http://stackoverflow.com/a/37898582/3664759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned in Restangular docs:

Because Restangular returns promises, we can then call methods on the returned data on promises so that we can run a function after the promise has completed. For instance, after we update a collection, we can then refresh the collection on our scope:

```
messages.post(newMessage).then(function(newMsg) {
  $scope.messages = messages.getList();
}, function error(reason) {
  // An error has occurred
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was having an issue with understanding promise chaining and that's why this approach seemed odd, sorted now!